# Solo mining ETHEREUM using ethminer

Tags: ethminer

I have been thinking:"All tutorials show you how to mine in a pool, but i want to mine solo." And now I finally decided to ask this here. Does anyone know how to use ethminer to mine solo and set wallet adress to custom outside of geth?

Comment: I’m failing to find code for solo mining in ethminer : a pool miner client just only need code to get work, not to check if balance in a specific transaction is enough.